# adjust video at bottom of view with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, swift5

I am new to the world of iOS I came across a case that I don't know how to deal with.

I have an mp4 video which I am showing in the view with AVPlayer, my problem is that it always appears in the central part of the view. What I want to do is position it at the bottom of the view. How can I do that?

I leave the code that I am using, it is a basic implementation of AVPlayer.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoName, ofType: "mp4")!))
    let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    layer.frame = view.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the frame of the main view for the Avplayerlayer.that causes it to takes your whole Screen. Use this function to add a video to your view bottom.

```
 func addvideoToBottom(heightPercent value:CGFloat ) {
    let bottomView = UIView()
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .black
    self.view.addSubview(bottomView)
    bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: value).isActive = true
    bottomView.layoutIfNeeded()
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4")!))
    let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    layer.frame = bottomView.bounds
    bottomView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    player.play()
}
```

and call this function like this from your **viewdidAppear**

```
addvideoToBottom(heightPercent: 0.3)
```

0.3 means video frame height is 30% of your mobile Screen.**heightPercent** should be between 0 and 1 based on your requirement.